# Is there a way to have a root element wrapper with javax.xml?

Tags: java, xml, jersey

I have a Jeresey application. I have several resources that use beans annotated with javax.xml annotations for providers so the result returns in xml or json depending on what is sent in the accept header with xml being the default. All that works fine. Now, I need to add a root element to every response.

Here is a sample Provider Bean that the resource sets with data and returns the result.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "error")
public class ErrorProvider {


private String errorCode;
private String errorMessage;

public ErrorProvider(){}

public ErrorProvider(final String errorCode,final String errorMessage){
    setErrorCode(errorCode);
    setErrorMessage(errorMessage);
}

@XmlAttribute(name = "number")
public String getErrorCode() {
    return errorCode;
}

public void setErrorCode(final String errorCode) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
}

@XmlElement
public String getErrorMessage() {
    return errorMessage;
}

public void setErrorMessage(final String errorMessage) {
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
}
}
```

The produces annotation on the resource method is:

```
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
```

So the default return is in XML unless json is defined in the accept header of the request. Like I said, this works fine. It returns something like this:

```
<error code="100">
    <errorMessage>An error occurred</errorMessage>
</error>
```

OK, enough with the backdrop, now with the question. I need to add a root element to all of these providers, which will be the same for all. So it would look like this:

```
<transaction>
    <status>ok</status>
    <error code="100">
        <errorMessage>An error occurred</errorMessage>
    </error>
</transaction>
```

It would be cool to have something like an @XmlElementWrapper at the class level. I tried creating another bean annotated with the javax.xml and tried to extend it, tried to do a generic type bean. I just can't figure it out. The best thing I was able to do is to have the transaction annotation inside the error XML like it was another element. I know I could edit each provider bean to include the transaction root element, but I think there should be a way to create that once and apply to every provider bean.

Comment: Couldn't you create a Bean called `Transaction` with a field `status` and another field `error` of type `ErrorProvider` and add the annotations appropriately?

Comment: Take [a deeper at how jaxb works](http://blog.xebia.com/2011/03/17/jaxb-xml-data-binding), I guess you're looking for `@XmlType` but I'm not sure of understanding your question

Comment: T Man - I thought of that and it worked fairly well for that one case, but I have multiple Provider beans that I need to do this with, so it was not a feasible solution to have multiple Provider type fields in the main Transaction bean.

Comment: I'll look at XmlType further, it didn't seem to do what I wanted when I read about it. All the provider beans work fine - I just need to wrap all of them in a standard element on return - hopefully that helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a ContainerResponseFilter that wraps your responses using the Transaction object. This is how it could look like (untested):

```
public class MyFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {
    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest request, ContainerResponse response) {
        response.setEntity(new Transaction(response.getEntity()));
        return response;
    }
}
```

You can find out more about how to register filters here: http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/container/filter/package-summary.html

Comment: That sounds promising. It sounds like the response from the resource method would be filtered through there where I could apply the standard wrapper elements. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: That's right - you would have a Transaction bean (annotated with XmlRootElement), when the filter gets invoked, it would modify the response such that it wraps the current entity by the Transaction object. So, once Jersey tries to marshall, it should spit out the right thing. Make sure your Transaction class has the public default constructor as well as one that takes the type you want to wrap (the above code should cast to that type as it gets passed to Transaction constructor).

Comment: That actually works great, and I think that is the better way of doing it, on the way out. I want the filter to be used for every response, but the entity could be an instance of any provider bean. This is the only way I've been able to do it. Define a property on the transaction bean for every provider bean the entity could be. On the filter check the instanceof the entity and cast it apporpriately. Is there a way to gernify the whole process? I'm not sure how to setup the transaction bean to know about the different types it may need to handle.